# Loopable custom functoid in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I've got the following custom functoid in two kinds.

[image: Custom functoid]

First one:

```cs
public class MyClass : BaseFunctoid
{

    public MyClass() : base()
    {
        // Settings for functoid

        this.SetExternalFunctionName(this.GetType().Assembly.FullName, this.GetType().FullName, "MyMethod");
        this.SetMinParams(2);
        this.SetMaxParams(2);

        this.AddInputConnectionType(ConnectionType.Element | ConnectionType.Field);
        this.AddInputConnectionType(ConnectionType.Element | ConnectionType.Field | ConnectionType.FunctoidCount | ConnectionType.FunctoidMath | ConnectionType.FunctoidString);
        this.OutputConnectionType = ConnectionType.Record | ConnectionType.Element | ConnectionType.Field | ConnectionType.FunctoidLooping;

        this.HasSideEffects = false;
    }

    public string[] MyMethod(string arg1, int arg2)
    {
        // do something

        return returnArray;
    }
}
```

This creates the following xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0 userCSharp" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="urn:mySchema1/1.0.0" xmlns:s0="urn:mySchema2/1.0.0" xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:Root" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/s0:Root">
        <ns0:DestinationRoot>
            <ns0:sync>
                <xsl:for-each select="s0:RepeatingNode">
                    <xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="position()" />
                    <ns0:statement>
                        <xsl:attribute name="sqlType">
                            <xsl:text>Update</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="script">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$var:v1" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </ns0:statement>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ns0:sync>
        </ns0:DestinationRoot>
    </xsl:template>

    <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="userCSharp"><![CDATA[

    ]]></msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Second one:

```cs
public class MyClass : BaseFunctoid
{

    public MyClass() : base()
    {
        // Settings for functoid

        this.AddScriptTypeSupport(ScriptType.CSharp);
        this.SetScriptBuffer(ScriptType.CSharp, GetCSharpBuffer());
        this.SetMinParams(2);
        this.SetMaxParams(2);

        this.AddInputConnectionType(ConnectionType.Element | ConnectionType.Field);
        this.AddInputConnectionType(ConnectionType.Element | ConnectionType.Field | ConnectionType.FunctoidCount | ConnectionType.FunctoidMath | ConnectionType.FunctoidString);
        this.OutputConnectionType = ConnectionType.Record | ConnectionType.Element | ConnectionType.Field | ConnectionType.FunctoidLooping;

        this.HasSideEffects = false;
    }

    private string GetCSharpBuffer()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("\n");
        sb.Append("public string[] MyMethod(string arg1, int arg2)\n");
        sb.Append("{\n");
        sb.Append("\t// do something\n");
        sb.Append("\treturn returnArray;\n");
        sb.Append("}");

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public string[] MyMethod(string arg1, int arg2)
    {
        // do something

        return returnArray;
    }
}
```

creates the following xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0 userCSharp" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="urn:mySchema1/1.0.0" xmlns:s0="urn:mySchema2/1.0.0" xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:Root" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/s0:Root">
    <ns0:DestinationRoot>
        <ns0:sync>
            <xsl:for-each select="s0:RepeatingNode">
                <xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="position()" />
                    <ns0:statement>
                        <xsl:attribute name="sqlType">
                            <xsl:text>Update</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="script">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$var:v1" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </ns0:statement>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ns0:sync>
        </ns0:DestinationRoot>
    </xsl:template>
    <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="userCSharp"><![CDATA[

        public string[] TestMethod(string input, int maxPerItem)
        {
            return returnArray;
        }

    ]]></msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In both cases the following XML is created:

```
<ns0:DestinationRoot xmlns:ns0="urn:mySchema1/1.0.0">
    <ns0:sync>
        <ns0:statement sqlType="Update" script="1" />
    </ns0:sync>
</ns0:DestinationRoot>
```

With `XmlNodeList` as return type I get an item for each node in this list. But only the counter is raising the number. The code will not be executed.

The Intention of this functoid is that I want to split a field from the input XML by certain conditions (not by a specified character) and for each item I need an element in the output XML with the value of this item. But in this configuration I get only a counter and the functoid function isn't call.

What have I to do that the functoid is loopable by the looping functoid and the code of the functoid is called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping over a scripting functoid in BizTalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046561/looping-over-a-scripting-functoid-in-biztalk)

Comment: Sorry for the questionable mod hammer.  See the other answer.  You should probably delete this question.

Comment: That is no duplicate. The problem is simliar and this are two different tries to solve it. In this question I want to create a functoid which is loopable (= Why doesn't work my functoid how it should? What do I wrong). The other question is the same issue but with sripting functoid (= Is it possible two loop over a node set which is created in scripting functoid?). Almost the same but in detail a little bit different. ;-)

Comment: I know.  The moderator was wrong in not seeing the subtle differences in the question.  Though the Answer is still the same.